# How can i convert this AJAX json result (which has a key/value property) into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest

Given the following json result, how can I convert the `validationErrors` key/value property into a nice array object in javascript so i can then do things like

`errors[0].Key`

or

`errors[0].Value`, etc...

[image]

NOTE: If it's easier to do the conversion with jQuery, then I'm happy to use that. Also, I'm getting the data via jQuery -> `$.post`...)

update:

Here's the actual json data so someone can answer this with JSFiddle please.

```
{
  "aaaa": 0,
  "bbbb": 0,
  "cccc": null,
  "validationErrors": {
    "a1_7127763-1c7ac823-61d5-483f-a9ca-4947e9eb8145": "Invalid PropertyType. Please choose any property except Unknown.",
    "a2_7127763-1c7ac823-61d5-483f-a9ca-4947e9eb8145": "A State is required. Eg. Victoria or New South Wales.",
    "b1_5433417-18b5568a-d18e-45e2-9c63-30796995e2d3": "Invalid PropertyType. Please choose any property except Unknown.",
    "b2_5433417-18b5568a-d18e-45e2-9c63-30796995e2d3": "A State is required. Eg. Victoria or New South Wales.",
    "c1_6655305-297c57f9-a460-4101-be7d-70c6b9a565d5": "Invalid PropertyType. Please choose any property except Unknown.",
    "c2_6655305-297c57f9-a460-4101-be7d-70c6b9a565d5": "A State is required. Eg. Victoria or New South Wales."
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the actual JSON data?  We need to see the actual structure and properties on your data to know how to advise you.

Comment: just pass the datype parameter of post function as `json` jquery will convert it autometically.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're looking at the full structure! it's a screen shot of the json result with stuff blacked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to convert the object to an array:

```
var errors = jQuery.map(data.validationErrors, function (value, key) {
    return {
        "Key": key,
        "Value": value
    };
});
```

JSFiddle showing this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/WgaFb/1/

---

If you do not wish to use jQuery, here is a pure JavaScript method:

```
var errors = [];
for(var key in data.validationErrors) {
    errors.push({
        "Key": key,
        "Value": data.validationErrors[key]
    });
}
```

JSFiddle for this second approach: http://jsfiddle.net/4WXEF/1/

Comment: Updated opening topic/post with sample data, for your JSFiddle example :)

Comment: @Pure.Krome I have updated the JSFiddle links to include your data example. You will see that the middle part of each one is a direct copy-paste from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would take all the keys of the object and then map them to an array.

```
var arrayOfErrors = Object.keys(objectOfErrors).map(function(errorKey) {
  return objectOfErrors[errorKey];
});
```

Comment: is map a jQuery or JS method?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @FelixKling—I guess stuff at MDN is, strictly, JavaScript™, but I think the OP really wants to know if it's plain ECMAScript, which it is: [*Object.keys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14), [*Array.prototype.map*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19).

Comment: @RobG: MDN links to the specification as well though.